# Book and article recommendations with the purpose of studying the intersection between probability theory and lattice theory

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, textbook-recommendation, lattice-theory

Lately, I have been studying probability theory and lattice theory separately and I would like to investigate ideas which relate both subjects together. Having said that, I would like to know if someone could provide me references such as books or articles that explore the intersection between such domains, which would considerably shorten my search for them.

Comment: I think that Catherine Yan's Ph.D. thesis deals with lattice theory and probability. https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/43462/37924038-MIT.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y